Canvas App Responsiveness in Mobile and Tablet views
I have a canvas app (Tablet mode), and I would like to be responsive on a computer, tablet, and mobile phone.  I can't seem to get the layout correct.  This app just contains a SharePoint form with a bunch of fields.  Documentation I've read really only suggests creating an app with containers, but I've already built the app without containers.  Is there another way to do this?  It currently looks great on desktop and tablet, but mobile looks very small and squished vertically.  Do I have an option here, or do I just need to compromise and modify the width?
Thank you.
